# AEM Authoring automation-unable to locate the element

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber, aem

We have requirement to implement automated testing for AEM authoring functionality. We have created automation suite using Selenium and cucumber frameworks and we're able to automatically login to AEM and able create pages using required template.

But once page is created we're unable to locate container component element to drag and drop the components. Please see the screenshots below DOM for container component.

If you implemented similar. Please share your thoughts.

And also, please share your thoughts if you implemented automation for AEM authoring functionality for Touch UI in AEM 6.5.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We have been successfully used [qaf-support-aem](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-aem) for same use case. You should try [qaf-support-aem](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-aem) library that provides ready to use components and [utility methods/steps](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-aem/blob/master/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/step/AEMAuthoringSteps.java).

This library provides two way to create new page:

1. [create new page](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-aem/blob/5f5ba417d5510d2ecd323ffc3d90ddd3edf70231/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/step/AEMAuthoringSteps.java#L53) using ui
2. [create new page](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-aem/blob/5f5ba417d5510d2ecd323ffc3d90ddd3edf70231/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/step/AEMAuthoringSteps.java#L67) using api

To edit newly created page or an existing page

```
AEMEditorPage editorPage = new AEMEditorPage();
//uncomment below statement if you are not on requested page 
//for example page created through api or opening existing page
//editorPage.launchPage(pagepath);
```

AEMEditorPage will provide you access to edit menus and editable component placeholder. You can refer [AEMEditorPage](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-aem/blob/master/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/ui/aem/admin/pages/AEMEditorPage.java) for more available functionality.

Library requires following properties:

```
env.aem.baseurl=<aem instance base url>
aem.user=<aem user>
#aem.password=<aem password>
encrypted.aem.password=<base64 encrypted password>
```

Further more if you are using cucumber and love to use cucumber, you take benefit of [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber)